# How do you remove the 'flicker' when switching img src on hover?

Tags: html, css

http://mintrain.co.uk/portfolio.html

Here is my test server for my latest website. Having an issue with changing img src on hover. In Safari and Chrome, when hovering over the image with the mouse it 'flickers' white before displaying the image. After this initial flicker, re-hovering works as intended.
Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
        <div class="maxw">

            <div class="pbox">
                <div class="image" id="one"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="pbox">
                <div class="image" id="two"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="pbox">
                <div class="image" id="three"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="pbox">
                <div class="image" id="four"></div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.pbox {
    width: 45%;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
}


 #one {
    background: url(/images/portfolio/1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


#one:hover {
    background: url(/images/portfolio/1A.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

etc etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you use `filter: grayscale(100%);` ? https://jsfiddle.net/ncsk0eao/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
 #one {
    background: url(/images/portfolio/1A.jpg) no-repeat; //same image here
    background-size: contain;
    transition: 0.3s;
    filter: grayscale(100%);

}


#one:hover {
    background: url(/images/portfolio/1A.jpg) no-repeat; //same image here
    background-size: contain;
    filter: grayscale(0%);

}
```

Comment: You have `IA` not `1A`

Comment: Np problem, Fixed the IA to 1A :-)

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case you can use `filter: grayscale(1)` and transition that instead.

But more generally, if you had a different image, you could layer them.

```css
#one:hover {
    background-image: url(/images/portfolio/1A.jpg), url(/images/portfolio/1.jpg);
}
```

The reason the flicker happens, by the way, is that changing the background image unloads the current one and then loads in the new one, which takes a moment if the new one isn't cached yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, filter grayscale works much better